# list's index() method for nested structures OR how to match against particular value of composed element stored in list and get it's index

Tags: python

It is possible to get index of particular element in list using `index()` method, following way (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)):

```
>>> ["foo", "bar", "baz"].index('bar')
1
```

Is it possible to apply the same principle to nested structures (if not what is the closest most pythonic way)? The result should looks like this:

```
In [20]: list
Out[20]: [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)]
In [21]: list.someMagicFunctionHere(,4,)
Out[20]: 1
```

Comment: I would think the pythonic way would be to do some reading then try a few things out till it feels right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the element in a container in your list:

```
def get_nested_index(list_, element):
    for index, container in enumerate(list_):
        if element in container:
             return index

    # If we made it here, it wasn't in any of the containers
    raise ValueError("{element} not in any element in list".format(element=element))
```

-

```
>>> get_nested_index([(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)], 4)
1
```

You can read about [`enumerate` here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) if you haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

adding to Navith's solution index...

```
def get_nested_index(list_, element):
    lt = []
    for index, container in enumerate(list_):
        if element in container:
             t = index, container.index(element)
        lt.append(t)
        t = ()
    return lt

print(get_nested_index([(0, 1, 4, 2), (3, 4, 5)], 4))
```

output
[(0, 2), (1, 1)]